# Is there a proof reading website where users can submit their problems and upload their proof documents to be reviewed?

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing, proof-verification

I'm just looking for a proof reading website that would allow a user to post her/his problem to be proved and her/his scanned documents to their claimed proof to the problem. I was just about to post my problem set with a link to the documents I've compiled proving them, namely my solution set, but I suspect that isn't allowed here. Any suggestions would be nice.

Comment: In my opinion, if you replace "link to document" with verbatim text and do so for one proof at a time, "here" would not be totally wrong.